# Nested object values does not follow in parameter from ajax call to actionmethod

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, signalr

The nested object values in the parameter does not follow. How can i get the full object including the nested values to follow in the actionmethod in the controller?

There is values in the object inside the red ring on the pictures when i call the ajac method. But does not follow in the controller

```
mapHub.client.requestForHelpInClient = function (requestDetails) {
                debugger;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: '@Url.Action("RequestPartialView", "Supplier")',
                    data: requestDetails,
                    success: function (response) {
                        $("#Request").html(response);
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                });                }
```

[image]

```
  function requestForHelp() {
            requestDetails = {
                CustomerId: @Model.Customer.CustomerID,
                NumberOfHours: $("#numberOfHoursTextBox").val(),
                TypeOfMachine: $("#typeOfMachineDropDownMenu").children("option:selected").val(),
                CustomerLocation: CustomerPosition,
                NearestSupplierList: nearestSuppliers
                //StartDate: $( "#startDate" ).val(),
                //EndDate: $( "#endDate" ).val(),
            }
            mapHub.server.requestForHelp(requestDetails);


public class RequestDetails
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public MapClient CustomerLocation { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfHours { get; set; }
    public string TypeOfMachine { get; set; }
    public List<MapClient> NearestSupplierList { get; set; }    
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

The signalr hub

```
 public void RequestForHelp(RequestDetails requestDetails)
    {

        requestDetails.Customer =   Service.CustomerService.GetCustomerById(requestDetails.CustomerId);
Service.SupplierService.GetAspNetUserIDBySupplierID(requestDetails.NearestSupplierList[0].ClientId);

            Clients.User(supplierAspNetUserID).requestForHelpInClient(requestDetails);
    }
```

Comment: Can you post how the serialized JSON is stored in `requestDetails`?

Comment: what do you mean? I have added the js code that creates the requestdetails @user1672994

Comment: In server side code, `CustomerId` is part of `Customer` object, but it seems that while sending, it is direct property of `RequestDetails`. Should the Json at client side follow the required schema of server Model class?

Comment: Yes customerid is both in customer(inside requestDetails) and a property of its own in requestDetails. I have aded some more code that might help

Comment: I'm not seeing, you passing `Customer` object in `requestForHelp` method; that's why the object's properties at received model is null.

Comment: Add the `[FromBody]` tag to the request object in the controller. Like this: `public void RequestForHelp([FromBody]RequestDetails requestDetails)`

Comment: @user1672994 i populate the customer in the signalr hub method RequestForHelp() .

Comment: @nurdyguy The frombody keyword does not exist

Comment: i made a new post where i have explained it much better. I will delete this one after awhile. See link for new question... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58622622/push-parameter-from-ajax-call-to-action-method-does-not-return-full-object-corre

Comment: @RobelHaile Right-click, quick actions, add the using.  That tag absolutely does exist. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: There is no 'add using' option. Do you know what reference/using that is needed? I might be missing the correct dll

Comment: If you add the tag and it has the red squiggly under it then right-click and the context menu will have a "Quick actions and refactorings" (with a yellow light bulb).  Click that and another context menu will show with possible solutions.  The first one will say something like "using ______".  If you click that it will add the `using`.  This is the easiest way to add missing `using` statements.  I don't know which version of MVC you are on so I don't know what using you are missing.

Comment: I was missing a reference. Now i can use frombody. But it does not help my issue, any other suggestions @nurdyguy

Comment: Can't believe I didn't see this earlier... You are using a `GET` method. You cannot send data like that to a `GET`.  Change it to a `POST` in both the controller and the ajax.

Comment: It is working now thank you so much! The change from get to post did the work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two quick changes for you.

1. You are using a `GET` method.  `GET` methods cannot transfer data like that.  Change the `GET` to a `POST` in both the controller and the ajax.
2. You need to add a `[FromBody]` tag in the controller.  Depending on which version of MVC you are on the data binder can be extra picky about that.

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RequestPartialView([FromBody]RequestDetails reqDetails)
{
   // code here 
}
```

Ajax:

```
mapHub.client.requestForHelpInClient = function (requestDetails) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("RequestPartialView", "Supplier")',
        data: requestDetails,
        success: function (response) {
            $("#Request").html(response);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });  
}
```